# Refresh datalist in view after user finishes typing in textbox Angular 7

Tags: html, angular, typescript, web, dom

I am trying to refresh a datalist in the view after waiting for user to finish typing in the textbox and updating results. Tried with angular directives, tried with Observable and various timeouts and debounces and no luck. I ran out of options.

In the html file:

```
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Other"  
            (keyup)="onKeySearch($event)" list="dynamicList" formControlName="Other"/>

            <datalist id="dynamicList">
                <option *ngFor="let employee of employeesList" [value]="employee.Name">
                    {{employee.Name}}</option>
            </datalist>
```

in the .ts file:

```
  public employeesList: EmployeeData[] = [];

  timeout: any = null;

  getEmployeesList(name : string) {
      let empList: EmployeeData[] = [];

      // get employees list from service 
      this.employeeService.getEmployeesList(name).subscribe((data: any) => {
        empList = data;
        console.log(empList)
      })
      return empList;
    }

  public onKeySearch(event: any) {
    let empListt: EmployeeData[] = [];

    clearTimeout(this.timeout);
    var $this = this;
    this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        empListt = $this.getEmployeesList(event.target.value);
        console.log(empListt)
    }, 1000);
    this.employeesList = empListt;
  }
```

The problem is that the datalist is not updates after retrieving the data an populating the list. After it exists the method the list is again empty, thus no data to display.

**I have added stackblitz example code with similar code as above (same behavior):**

.ts file:

```
import { Component, VERSION, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FormControl } from "@angular/forms";
import { distinctUntilChanged, debounceTime, tap } from "rxjs/operators";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  searchControl = new FormControl("");
  message = "";
  public employeesList: string[] = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        tap(() => (this.message = "User is typing...")),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        debounceTime(1000)
      )
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.message = "User finished typing!";
        this.employeesList.push('1');
        this.employeesList.push('2');
        this.employeesList.push('3');
      });
  }
}
```

.html file:

```
<input [formControl]="searchControl" list="dynamicList">

<datalist id="dynamicList">
    <option *ngFor="let employee of employeesList">
        {{employee}}</option>
</datalist>

<span> {{message}} </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

The dropdown will be filtered according to the text you have entered. So, in the given example, since you have pushed 1,2 and 3 values into the list, the drop down will only list with the filtered value.

Eg. if you input 1, the drop down list will have 1 (which is the required functionality)

You can see this behavior clearly if you slightly change the test input as :

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        tap(() => (this.message = "User is typing...")),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        debounceTime(1000)
      )
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.message = "User finished typing!";
        this.employeesList.push('Employee 1');
        this.employeesList.push('Employee 2');
        this.employeesList.push('Employee 3');
      });
  }
```

Now, when you search 'Employee', it will list all 3, and if you search 'Employee 1', it will list the required one entry only. (*Which is the expected behavior*)

Answer (score 0):

Your `formControl` (called 'Other', for some reason) has an `event` that is emitted as an `Observable` on each change. You can `subscribe` to that event, and use the RxJS operator `debounceTime()` to specify how many milliseconds should it wait for the user to stop typing until the event is emitted.

I have created a simple [DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uxnu59), maybe it's easier to understand.

Good luck!

Comment: yes, i understood perfectly. the problem is not displaying the list using {{ }} in the UI, the problem is that the dataList which is supposed to create my dropdown is not refreshing

Comment: I have added stackblitz code example with the modified changes above

Comment: Can you please add the code in Stackblitz and share the link, instead of pasting the code here? Thanks!